# Ubuntu for phone naming and branding

Tags: ubuntu-touch, branding

What's the official name for referring to Ubuntu running on a smartphone? I've heard it variously referred to as "Ubuntu", "Ubuntu Phone", "Ubuntu Phone OS", "Ubuntu for phones" and probably more.

Also, is the interface used on phones called "Unity", or is it called something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now seems that everyone's settled on "Ubuntu Touch" to refer to the phone/tablet environment.

Comment: +1, Looks to be official too: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch

Answer (score 4):

The press talk about "Ubuntu Phone".

Canonical calls it "Ubuntu for Phones", which should be correct, since they code and publish it and therefore should know best how their products are named.

See also: http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone/

To answer your second question: The UI is a customized Unity Shell as seen in desktop Ubuntu and is also called Unity. The main difference is it's customized for touch gestures.

Comment: I agree that what Canonical call it is the canonical (pardon the pun) name. The trouble is, Canonical seem to have lots of names for it too.  The main page on the website calls it "Ubuntu for phones", there's a blog post from the design team calling it "Ubuntu for the phone", and I've heard Mark Shuttleworth call it "the Ubuntu Phone OS"

Comment: "Ubuntu for phones" and "Ubuntu for the phone" is essentially the same thing: it's **Ubuntu** running on a phone

Answer (score 2):

It's **Ubuntu** all the way, it just happens to be running on other devices :)

Comment: That's what the marketing engine produces, but we don't know that yet. Release cycles, updates, hardware support, etc. are all unsure. And I tend to disagree on this answer in general: completely different are at least the UI, kernel, default apps, installation method, etc.

Comment: We definitely know that the UI is new, but is it still Unity? Will we have to say "Unity in phone mode"?

Comment: @gertvdijk, well, that's the best answer I can give you. The name of the OS should not be dependent on the release cycle. If you want still to call it another name, feel free to choose your pick :)

Comment: @Flimm, again, why call it another name? If it's Unity, why does it matter if it runs on the desktop, on the phone, or in any other device? One of the main goals of the Unity concept was to seamlessly extend to multiple devices, and we're finally seeing all the pieces coming into place now :)

Comment: @DavidPlanella: Take this hypothetical conversation: "How do I minimise a window in Unity?" "Do you mean Unity on the desktop, or Unity on the phone?" This could get old really quickly. We're all speculating, but based on the video, it does look like Unity for desktop and Unity for phones are different enough from a non-techy user's point of view to merit short-hand different nicknames.

Comment: @Flimm, that indeed makes sense from the Ask Ubuntu point of view (i.e. how to handle questions and answers), but a regular user will only be interested to know that they're running Ubuntu, regardless of the device. Btw, I'm not speculating, I answered with the information I have right now.

Comment: Not exactly answering the question. And is misleading. As the OP has specifically asked for "What's the official name for referring to Ubuntu running on a smartphone?"

Comment: And the answer is still Ubuntu. We've just recently announced the converged codebase across all devices, which should make this even clearer. But if you really need a separate name, you can use "Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview". In fact, we've already got the `ubuntu-touch` tag in Ask Ubuntu